# mysql_real_escape_string creates \ in server only not in local

Tags: php, sql

When I use mysql_real_escape_string in my localhost and I output the result of html in a table I have no problem. But when I use it on my server it outputs even the <kbd>\</kbd>

This is how I use it:

```
$_GETVARS['txtEmpNum'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GETVARS['txtEmpNum']);
$_GETVARS['txtLName'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GETVARS['txtLName']);
$_GETVARS['txtFName'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GETVARS['txtFName']);

$varSQL = "INSERT INTO admintool.atUsers(empNum,empLName,empFName,empLevel) VALUES('".$_GETVARS['txtEmpNum']."','".$_GETVARS['txtLName']."','".$_GETVARS['txtFName']."','".$_GETVARS['selectLevel']."')";
$result = ExecuteQuery2($varSQL, $LinkTESTOPS);
```

[image]

Result looks like this look at the 2\'s

[image]

Result in my localhost has no problem.

I don't understand where the problem is coming from.

The <kbd>\</kbd> is even inserted in the sql table. Only in the server of course. The local database table insert it as <kbd>2's</kbd>. But in my server database table it is inserted as <kbd>2\'s</kbd>

Comment: Check to see if your server has [magic quotes enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). [`get_magic_quotes_gpc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) is what you use to test if they are running.

Comment: True enough. When I use <kbd>get_magic_quotes_gpc()</kbd> in localhost it returns 0. And 1 in server. So it is on. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server has magic quotes enabled and your local server not. Remove it with the following sentence

```
set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)
```

As this function is deprecated and it will be deleted in PHP 7.0, I recommend you to change your php.ini with the following sentencies:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
```

If you cant go back and clean it, you can always use

```
stripslashes()
```

Comment: it seems this is the problem.

How do I use "set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)"? Because as I read some article magic quote cannot be changed in runtime and only in system level.